# Json parse cannot deserialize api call

Tags: javascript, java, json, spring-boot

I'm trying to send a json to my api, after several attempts of other solutions, I'm really stuck and can't find any solution anymore what I'm doing wrong. I have a post call recieved by following function

```
@PostMapping(path = "ts/sts")
    public void saveTestStep(@RequestBody TestStepDTO testStepDTO){
        TestStep testStep = new TestStep(testStepDTO.getTestCaseId(),
                testStepDTO.getStepNumber(),
                testStepDTO.getDescription(),
                testStepDTO.getTestdata(),
                testStepDTO.getPrerequisite(),
                testStepDTO.getResult());
        TestStepService testStepService = new TestStepService();
        testStepService.save(testStep);
    }
```

I call this with following javascript script

```
for(i=0;i<prerquisites.length;i++){

                        b = i+1;
                        $.ajax({
                            url: 'http://localhost:8080/ts/sts',
                            dataType: 'json',
                            type: 'post',
                            contentType: 'application/json',
                            data: [{ "result": result[i], "stepNumber": b, "description":  description[i],"testCaseId": 1 , "testdata": testdata[i], "prerequisite": prerquisites[i]}] ,
                            processData: false,
                            success: function( data, textStatus, jQxhr ){
                                $('#response pre').html( JSON.stringify( data ) );
                            },
                            error: function( jqXhr, textStatus, errorThrown ){
                                console.log( errorThrown );
                                console.log("testcaseid: " + testcaseid);
                            }
                        });
                    }
```

And I have my DTO class

```
public class TestStepDTO {

    @NotBlank
    private Integer testCaseId;
    @NotBlank
    private Integer stepNumber;
    @NotBlank
    private String description;
    @NotBlank
    private String result;
    @NotBlank
    private String testdata;
    @NotBlank
    private String prerequisite;

    public Integer getTestCaseId() {
        return testCaseId;
    }

    public void setTestCaseId(Integer testCaseId) {
        this.testCaseId = testCaseId;
    }

    public Integer getStepNumber() {
        return stepNumber;
    }

    public void setStepNumber(Integer stepNumber) {
        this.stepNumber = stepNumber;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public String getResult() {
        return result;
    }

    public void setResult(String result) {
        this.result = result;
    }

    public String getTestdata() {
        return testdata;
    }

    public void setTestdata(String testdata) {
        this.testdata = testdata;
    }

    public String getPrerequisite() {
        return prerequisite;
    }

    public void setPrerequisite(String prerequisite) {
        this.prerequisite = prerequisite;
    }
}
```

But when I run this I get the following error

```
2021-04-01 18:49:06.043  WARN 28296 --- [io-8080-exec-10] .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved [org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: JSON parse error: Cannot deserialize instance of `be.
tquality.TestManager.RestService.POJO.TestStepDTO` out of START_ARRAY token; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot deserialize instance of `be.tquality.TestManager.RestService.POJO.T
estStepDTO` out of START_ARRAY token
```

Does anybody know or see what I'm doing wrong in this process?

Comment: The error gives you a clue: `Cannot deserialize instance of 'be.tquality.TestManager.RestService.POJO.TestStepDTO' out of START_ARRAY token` TestStepDTO isn't an array type but your passing it up to the server as an array.

Comment: I am not an UI person, but can you somehow log/see the actual json that. you generate from UI, _before_ it hits the back-end? This will most probably show that you generate an _array_, exactly as the error states.

Comment: When you want to post json with $.ajax you have to stringify the object yourself

Answer (score 0):

Remove the square brackets on your data line in your ajax post call.

```
data: [{ "result": result[i]... }]
```

Should be

```
data: { "result": result[i] ... }
```

That's sending the json to the API as an array because the square brackets `[]` is array notation, around the curly bracket `{}` object notation.

Comment: This is my date line, but still the same issue: data: { "result": result[i], "stepNumber": b, "description":  description[i],"testCaseId": 1 , "testdata": testdata[i], "prerequisite": prerquisites[i]} ,